# Passing int value from one jFrame to another jFrame using ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I Have two classes, I am using ActionListeners, the thing is that i want to receive an int value in the First class from the Second One...
THE FIRST CLASS is this one:

```
public class PanelCotizacion extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private int numCotizacion = 0;
    public PanelCotizacion() {
        initComponents();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO RECEIVE THE VALUE");
        this numCotizacion = "";
        //THE VALUE THAT I WANT TO RECEIVE FROM THE OTHER jFRAME
        //TRIGGERED BY THE EVENT OF THE BUTTON (action performed)
    }
}
```

This is the Second One, where i want to send the int value:

```
public class BusquedaCotizacionGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private int numCotizacion = 0;
    public BusquedaCotizacionGUI() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        PanelCotizacion pC = new PanelCotizacion();
        this.cmdOK.addActionListener(pC);
    }
    private void cmdOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        this.numCotizacion = Integer.parseInt(this.txtNumCotizacion.getText());
        //Here is where I WANT TO PASS THE VARIABLE "numCotizacion" tho the other class
        //Can Somebody Help Me
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Can you help me guys to do this, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

From your code i think the `BusquedaCotizacionGUI JFrame` responsible to open the `PanelCotizacion Jpanel` and pass your variable.

So there is many ways to pass a variable from `JFrame` to `JPanel`.

You can create a constructor taking an int parameter, then pass the variable in the constructor, like:

```
public PanelCotizacion(int numCotizacion) {
    initComponents();
    this.numCotizacion = numCotizacion;
}
```

or you could pass the `JFrame` as a parent component to `JPanel` to the constructor, then get the value by creating a getting method, like,

```
private JFrame parent;
public PanelCotizacion(JFrame parent) {
    initComponents();
    this.parent= parent;
}
```

then get the value like:

```
parent.getNumCotizacion();
```

Comment: Thanks Salah for your comment, the constructor taking an int parameter doesnt work, and the second option i don't know where to put this into my code "parent.getNumCotizacion();" cause it generates me errors, i Forget too mention that the panel that i use i already change it many time with others panels, using the removeAll(); .add(component), .updateUI(); so i dont know if that affect why i could't see the update of the variable numCotizacion, i'm going to try the answer of Kojotak

Answer (score 0):

There is `Object getSource()` method in `ActionEvent` class, so in your ActionListener you can get the source and cast it to `PanelCotizacion`. Other possibility is to add reference to your `BusquedaCotizacionGUI` into `PanelCotizacion`'s constructor.

Answer (score 0):

in your second JFrame (BusquedaCotizacionGUI) add this line of code (sth ike this) :

```
 PanelCotizacion.setParam(int parameterToPass)
```

and in the first JFrame (PanelCotizacion) add a method (say setParam) and an integer field (say myField):

```
 public void setParam (int param) {
 this.myField = param;
}
```

**You** should decide about how to implement this idea (static method vs creating an instance of the first JFrame,...); this is just the general idea, customize it so as to fit your desire.

Comment: thanks for your answer mok but it doesn't work, i got an error in PanelCotizacion, another way to pass the value?

Comment: you're welcome, how did you call the setParam and please give more details about the error.

Comment: "non static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context", thanks for your help again!

Comment: Oh what a mistake! You're right. I'm sorry :) I'll fix it right now. just create a sample of the other JFrame using new and call the setParam using the created object and just make the myField static.

Comment: How can i do that? this is my code:
public static void setParam(int parseInt) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        this.numCotizacion = parseInt;
    }
and my variable is:
public static int numCotizacion = 0;

But i have the same warning!

Comment: just use public void setParam(int parseInt) {}. and inside that add this : this.myField = parseInt. remember myField should be static.